# I have to access only -ve values of balance

Tags: oracle10g

```
select sum(b.budget) as  Budget,sum(b.rev) as Revised,sum(b.expe) as  Expenditure,(sum(b.budget) + sum(b.rev) - sum(b.expe))   as balance,
b.accounts,b.abac_code,
b.abac_name,b.dac_code,b.dac_name,b.abacname
 from 
 (
select upper('Budget') typ,a.sl abac_sl,a.code abac_code,a.name abac_name,d.code dac_code,d.name dac_name,a.code || ' - ' || a.name abacname 
,0 Accounts,nvl(sum(nvl(g3.amt,0)),0) as budget,0 rev,0 expe
from abac a,dac d,acct_master ac,gl3 g3
where g3.acct_sl=ac.sl and a.sl=ac.afld_sl4  and d.sl =afld_sl5 and upper(g3.typ) = upper('budget') 
and d.sl in (select sl from selall where upper(table_name) = upper('dac') and user_sl = :user_sl )
and a.sl in (select sl from selall where upper(table_name) = upper('abac3') and upper(typ) = upper('pabac') and user_sl = :user_sl )
and g3.drange_sl = :drange_sl
group by a.sl,a.code ,a.name ,d.code,d.name
union all
select upper('Revised') typ,a.sl abac_sl,a.code abac_code,a.name abac_name,d.code dac_code,d.name dac_name,a.code || ' - ' || a.name abacname,
0 Accounts,0 budget,nvl(sum(nvl(rev_amt,0)),0) as rev,0 expe 
from abac a,dac d,acct_master ac,gl3 g3
where g3.acct_sl=ac.sl and a.sl=ac.afld_sl4  and d.sl =afld_sl5 and upper(g3.typ) = upper('budget') 
and d.sl in (select sl from selall where upper(table_name) = upper('dac') and user_sl = :user_sl )
and a.sl in (select sl from selall where upper(table_name) = upper('abac3') and upper(typ) = upper('pabac') and user_sl = :user_sl )
and g3.drange_sl =:drange_sl
group by a.sl,a.code ,a.name ,d.code,d.name
union all 
select upper('Expenditure') typ,a.sl abac_sl,a.code abac_code,a.name abac_name,d.code dac_code,d.name dac_name,a.code || ' - ' || a.name abacname,
0 Accounts,0 budget,0 rev,nvl(sum(nvl((abs(g.amt)),0)),0) expe
from gl g,chq c,acct_master ac,abac a ,dac d
where upper(typ) = upper('pay2') and g.vouchr_no>0 and g.amt>0 and g.acct_sl =ac.sl and ac.afld_sl4 =a.sl and ac.afld_sl5 =d.sl
and g.chq_sl=c.sl and g.drange_sl =:drange_sl and c.doc_date between :from_date and :to_date 
and d.sl in (select sl from selall where upper(table_name) = upper('dac') and user_sl = :user_sl)
and a.sl in (select sl from selall where upper(table_name) = upper('abac3') and upper(typ) = upper('pabac') and user_sl = :user_sl )
group by a.sl,a.code ,a.name ,d.code,d.name
order by dac_code
) b  
group by b.abac_code,b.abac_name,b.dac_code,b.dac_name,b.abacname,b.accounts
order by balance
```

Comment: And what precisely do you expect us to do with that unformatted mess you've dumped here?

Comment: omg... would you share the problem with us?

Comment: its like a multiple query ...select a.name,b.code,c.add from (select name from a

Comment: its like a multiple query ... i show with simple example...
select d.name,d.code,d.add
from 
(
select name from a
union all
select code from b
union all
select add from c
) d

Comment: Please edit your question 1) In prose tell us what you want to do, what your problem is and what your question is 2) Use the format tools to format the code. 3) Make the title a question currently it is a statement. If you expect an answer you must ask a question. BTW: did you write `SQL` statement or got if from somewhere?

Comment: in this query i m getting balance,budget,expenditure etc... but i have to put condition 'balance < 0' ....its getting error like not a valid identifier...plz hlp me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference the balance you have to embrace it again into a subquery

```
 select * 
 from (
    select sum(b.budget) as Budget, 
           sum(b.rev)    as Revised,
           sum(b.expe)   as Expenditure,
           (sum(b.budget) + sum(b.rev) - sum(b.expe)) as balance,
           b.accounts, b.abac_code, b.abac_name, b.dac_code, b.dac_name, b.abacname
     from 
     (
         select upper('Budget') typ,a.sl abac_sl,a.code abac_code,a.name abac_name,d.code dac_code,d.name dac_name,a.code || ' - ' || a.name abacname 
        ,0 Accounts,nvl(sum(nvl(g3.amt,0)),0) as budget,0 rev,0 expe
        from abac a,dac d,acct_master ac,gl3 g3
        where g3.acct_sl=ac.sl and a.sl=ac.afld_sl4  and d.sl =afld_sl5 and upper(g3.typ) = upper('budget') 
        and d.sl in (select sl from selall where upper(table_name) = upper('dac') and user_sl = :user_sl )
        and a.sl in (select sl from selall where upper(table_name) = upper('abac3') and upper(typ) = upper('pabac') and user_sl = :user_sl )
        and g3.drange_sl = :drange_sl
        group by a.sl,a.code ,a.name ,d.code,d.name
      union all
        select upper('Revised') typ,a.sl abac_sl,a.code abac_code,a.name abac_name,d.code dac_code,d.name dac_name,a.code || ' - ' || a.name abacname,
        0 Accounts,0 budget,nvl(sum(nvl(rev_amt,0)),0) as rev,0 expe 
        from abac a,dac d,acct_master ac,gl3 g3
        where g3.acct_sl=ac.sl and a.sl=ac.afld_sl4  and d.sl =afld_sl5 and upper(g3.typ) = upper('budget') 
        and d.sl in (select sl from selall where upper(table_name) = upper('dac') and user_sl = :user_sl )
        and a.sl in (select sl from selall where upper(table_name) = upper('abac3') and upper(typ) = upper('pabac') and user_sl = :user_sl )
        and g3.drange_sl =:drange_sl
        group by a.sl,a.code ,a.name ,d.code,d.name
      union all 
        select upper('Expenditure') typ,a.sl abac_sl,a.code abac_code,a.name abac_name,d.code dac_code,d.name dac_name,a.code || ' - ' || a.name abacname,
        0 Accounts,0 budget,0 rev,nvl(sum(nvl((abs(g.amt)),0)),0) expe
        from gl g,chq c,acct_master ac,abac a ,dac d
        where upper(typ) = upper('pay2') and g.vouchr_no>0 and g.amt>0 and g.acct_sl =ac.sl and ac.afld_sl4 =a.sl and ac.afld_sl5 =d.sl
        and g.chq_sl=c.sl and g.drange_sl =:drange_sl and c.doc_date between :from_date and :to_date 
        and d.sl in (select sl from selall where upper(table_name) = upper('dac') and user_sl = :user_sl)
        and a.sl in (select sl from selall where upper(table_name) = upper('abac3') and upper(typ) = upper('pabac') and user_sl = :user_sl )
        group by a.sl,a.code ,a.name ,d.code,d.name
        order by dac_code
    ) b  
    group by b.abac_code,b.abac_name,b.dac_code,b.dac_name,b.abacname,b.accounts
  ) a
where balance < 0
order by balance
```

I have not tried it but you can also using the `HAVING` clause

```
select sum(b.budget) as Budget, 
           sum(b.rev)    as Revised,
           sum(b.expe)   as Expenditure,
           (sum(b.budget) + sum(b.rev) - sum(b.expe)) as balance,
           b.accounts, b.abac_code, b.abac_name, b.dac_code, b.dac_name, b.abacname
     from 
     (
         select upper('Budget') typ,a.sl abac_sl,a.code abac_code,a.name abac_name,d.code dac_code,d.name dac_name,a.code || ' - ' || a.name abacname 
        ,0 Accounts,nvl(sum(nvl(g3.amt,0)),0) as budget,0 rev,0 expe
        from abac a,dac d,acct_master ac,gl3 g3
        where g3.acct_sl=ac.sl and a.sl=ac.afld_sl4  and d.sl =afld_sl5 and upper(g3.typ) = upper('budget') 
        and d.sl in (select sl from selall where upper(table_name) = upper('dac') and user_sl = :user_sl )
        and a.sl in (select sl from selall where upper(table_name) = upper('abac3') and upper(typ) = upper('pabac') and user_sl = :user_sl )
        and g3.drange_sl = :drange_sl
        group by a.sl,a.code ,a.name ,d.code,d.name
      union all
        select upper('Revised') typ,a.sl abac_sl,a.code abac_code,a.name abac_name,d.code dac_code,d.name dac_name,a.code || ' - ' || a.name abacname,
        0 Accounts,0 budget,nvl(sum(nvl(rev_amt,0)),0) as rev,0 expe 
        from abac a,dac d,acct_master ac,gl3 g3
        where g3.acct_sl=ac.sl and a.sl=ac.afld_sl4  and d.sl =afld_sl5 and upper(g3.typ) = upper('budget') 
        and d.sl in (select sl from selall where upper(table_name) = upper('dac') and user_sl = :user_sl )
        and a.sl in (select sl from selall where upper(table_name) = upper('abac3') and upper(typ) = upper('pabac') and user_sl = :user_sl )
        and g3.drange_sl =:drange_sl
        group by a.sl,a.code ,a.name ,d.code,d.name
      union all 
        select upper('Expenditure') typ,a.sl abac_sl,a.code abac_code,a.name abac_name,d.code dac_code,d.name dac_name,a.code || ' - ' || a.name abacname,
        0 Accounts,0 budget,0 rev,nvl(sum(nvl((abs(g.amt)),0)),0) expe
        from gl g,chq c,acct_master ac,abac a ,dac d
        where upper(typ) = upper('pay2') and g.vouchr_no>0 and g.amt>0 and g.acct_sl =ac.sl and ac.afld_sl4 =a.sl and ac.afld_sl5 =d.sl
        and g.chq_sl=c.sl and g.drange_sl =:drange_sl and c.doc_date between :from_date and :to_date 
        and d.sl in (select sl from selall where upper(table_name) = upper('dac') and user_sl = :user_sl)
        and a.sl in (select sl from selall where upper(table_name) = upper('abac3') and upper(typ) = upper('pabac') and user_sl = :user_sl )
        group by a.sl,a.code ,a.name ,d.code,d.name
        order by dac_code
    ) b  
group by b.abac_code,b.abac_name,b.dac_code,b.dac_name,b.abacname,b.accounts
having (sum(b.budget) + sum(b.rev) - sum(b.expe))  < 0
order by balance
```